# serde error[E0275]: overflow evaluating the requirement `xxx: Deserialize<'_>`

Tags: rust, serde

So I have a tree which I would like to implement serde for and use the macro if possible.

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize)]
#[serde(bound(deserialize = "Node<H> : Deserialize<'de>"))]
pub struct SparseMerkleTree<H> {
    size: u64,
    root: Node<H>,
}

#[derive(Deserialize)]
#[serde(bound(deserialize = "BranchNode<H> : Deserialize<'de>, LeafNode<H> : Deserialize<'de>"))]
pub enum Node<H> {
    Empty(EmptyNode),
    Leaf(LeafNode<H>),
    Branch(BranchNode<H>),
}

#[derive(Deserialize)]
#[serde(bound(deserialize = "Box<Node<H>> : Deserialize<'de>"))]
pub struct BranchNode<H> {
    key: NodeKey,
    hash: NodeHash,
    left: Box<Node<H>>,
    right: Box<Node<H>>,
    hash_type: PhantomData<H>,
}
```

`EmptyNode` and `LeafNode<H>` are fine with the serde macro, `LeafNode<H>` has the same `hash_type: PhantomData<H>` requiring the generic `H`

But my problem comes with the Macro in that it runs into `error[E0275]: overflow evaluating the requirement`. Expanding the generated macro, it looks correct in that its implemented for the required bound, and not the generic `H` which it should not be for.

The Full error is this:

```
error[E0275]: overflow evaluating the requirement `Box<Node<_>>: Deserialize<'_>`
   --> src/sparse_merkle_tree/node.rs:180:28
    |
180 | #[derive(Deserialize)]
    |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^
    |
    = help: consider increasing the recursion limit by adding a `#![recursion_limit = "256"]` attribute to your crate 
note: required for `BranchNode<_>` to implement `Deserialize<'_>`
```

So what am I missing here? Or is this not possible at all and I have to manually implement serde here?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve with these relaxed bounds. For instance, for `Node`, how could deriving deserialization work without `EmptyNode: Deserialize<'de>`? And then if `EmptyNode: Deserialize<'de>`, you don't need the explicit bound at all.

Comment: Tip: You probably want to `#[serde(skip)]`  the `hash_type` if you're ever going to serialize this datastructure.

Comment: That `hash_type` is actually unneeded, since `H` is used for `Node<H>` already. It is most likely needed in `EmptyNode` only.

Comment: @V0ldek the compiler [will see that it's effectively unneeded in that case](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c0b9d92bb16bf85f0ec78655dcbc0334).

Comment: @cafce25 [But this works](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=487b12850adfeda259ab1753ea7240bf)

Not sure what the difference is.

Comment: @V0ldek the difference is that you added the `hash_type: PhantomData<H>` in `LeafNode` it's not optional, but where in the graph you put it is of no consequence.

Comment: @cafce25 you do not have to skip PhantomData<T> in serde anymore. Serde does implement serialize and deserialize for this.

Comment: @blackwolfsa you don't have to but it will generate a `"hash_type": null` if your serializing to json for example which very likely is unwanted as it's just an implementation detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the only generic in your structs is `H` and that doesn't affect (de-)serializability because it's not actually contained in any of the structs you show, your bounds are wrong, in fact you don't need any bounds at all which you can declare by putting nothing after `:`:

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize)]
#[serde(bound = "H:")]
pub struct SparseMerkleTree<H> {
    size: u64,
    root: Node<H>,
}
```

And similar for the other structs. If your other types implement `Deserialize` then this is enough for the derive macros to work their magic and implement it.

Comment: Awesome this works 100%. 
I was going of the example here: https://serde.rs/attr-bound.html
But its good to know you can leave out the bound